# How to retrieve tool-tip text of a button in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have the following HTML snippet below.  I want to retrieve the tool tip title (78)  of the button and use it in another function.

```
<span class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="78" onclick="showToolTipTitle(event);">10:15 AM</span>
```

I tried using  the following javascript codes to retrieve the tool-tip title but it still doesn't work:

```
function showToolTipTitle(event)
{   
    var title = $(event.target).attr("tooltip").text;
    alert(title);
}

function showToolTipTitle(event)
{   
    var title = $(event.target).attr("title");
    alert(title);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var new_title = $(this).attr("title");
        alert(new_title);
    });
});
</script>

<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="34">Display Tooltip</button>
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but it only displays an empty alert box

Comment: Please try this, Updated

Comment: how is that different from the functions in my question?

Comment: anyway, it still doesn't work. It only displays a blank alert box

Comment: can you please provide the fiddle for your code? It helps to debug issue. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84353/discussion-between-prasad-and-jpineds).